# Syntax check for constraint thats checks value of col1 = col2 * col3

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints

Might be something very simple regarding syntax that I've been doing wrong but for the past 2 hours i've been trying multiple statements when defining this constraint at both table and column levels as part of CREATE TABLE and tried the same separately using ALTER TABLE however haven't had any success:

```
Create table tb1 (
tb1_quantity number,
tb1_price number,
tb1_total number constraint tb1_total_CK
CHECK(tb1_total = SUM(tb1_quantity * tb1_price))
);
```

The other way i've been trying is:

```
Create table tb1 (
tb1_quantity number,
tb1_price number,
tb1_total number constraint tb1_total_CK
CHECK(SUM(tb1_quantity * tb1_price))
)
;
```

Seems to be something with the way i'm declaring the functions methinks since im constantly getting the usual ORA-00934 Group function not allowed here message. I have read multiple alternative ways using triggers and views but i'm eager to get it to work using a constraint, am I along the correct lines with this syntax or just not wording it properly ?

Comment: AFAIK, Oracle does not support table level constraint, but only row level.

Comment: If your version supports it, I'd recommend a [Virtual Column](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/virtual-columns-11gr1.php) instead - why force someone to calculate a value and then make sure they've done the calculation correctly, rather than have the system do the calculation directly? (Always assuming it makes sense to "store" a calculated value in the first place)

Comment: As it is, I'm not sure why you're using `SUM()` in your attempts.

Comment: `sum()` is an aggregate function working on a single column of multiple rows. You want a simple `+`

Comment: Seems I overcomplicated it a tad.

Answer (score 4):

you need to define this as an out of line constraint..i.e.:

```
Create table tb1 (
tb1_quantity number,
tb1_price number,
tb1_total number,
 constraint tb1_total_CK CHECK(tb1_total = tb1_quantity * tb1_price)
);
```

eg:

```
SQL> Create table tb1 (
  2  tb1_quantity number,
  3  tb1_price number,
  4  tb1_total number,
  5   constraint tb1_total_CK CHECK(tb1_total = tb1_quantity * tb1_price)
  6  );

Table created.


SQL> insert into tb1 values (1, 1, 1);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into tb1 values (1, 1, 2);
insert into tb1 values (1, 1, 2)
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02290: check constraint (DTD_TRADE.TB1_TOTAL_CK) violated
```

Comment: Thanks works now, I do remember doing something similar but was doing it column level which brought back the same issues mentioned earlier.